# Difference between XML::LibXML, XMl::DOM and XML::SAX

Tags: xml, dom, sax, libxml2, xml-libxml

What is the difference between XML::LibXML , XML::DOM and XML::SAX.
Can I use XML::LibXML only which should provide all the functionalities of XML::DOM and XML::SAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XML::SAX` is a framework to implement SAX parsers. It comes with `XML::SAX::PurePerl` which is a pure-Perl implementation but other XML modules can provide their own implementations sharing the same high-level API. One such module is `XML::LibXML`. An `XML::SAX` parser based on `XML::LibXML` will typically be faster than a pure-Perl solution.

`XML::DOM` is a module that provides a DOM Level 1 compliant XML manipulation API on top of `XML::Parser` which in turn is based on the *expat* C library. `XML::LibXML` is based on *libxml2* and provides its own implementation of the DOM interface (a large subset of DOM Level 3). So it should provide all of the functionality of `XML::DOM`.

To summarize, you can use only `XML::LibXML` for XML processing but `XML::SAX` is a dependency. If you use the `XML::LibXML` SAX parser, `XML::SAX` will be used behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I have one more doubt, if I use XML::LibXML then I can use XML::LibXML DOM and SAX in perl without explicitly installing it these modules.